# json script with kotlinx.html

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx-html

building html page using kotlinx.html

lots of content built without problems, but stumbling on adding json script tag with an id so the code on the client can retrieve the json data.

what to have the code something like..

```
<script id="jsondata" type="application/json">
   { "jsondata": "is here" }
</script>
```

using kotlinx.html i can have

```
            script(type="application/json"){
                    +"""{ "jsondata": "is here"}"""
            }
```

but unlike other tags, `script` does not seem to have an `id` property.  Any ideas on how to get set the id for the script tag?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is [Tag.attributes](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.html/blob/4cb5fa6cbdf0b8f3277d383cf8d062f872e54212/src/commonMain/kotlin/api.kt#L24) (mutable map with tag attributes).

```
script(type = "application/json") {
    attributes["id"] = "jsondata"
    unsafe { +"""{ "jsondata": "is here" }""" }
}
```

will give you this result:

```html
<script type="application/json" id="jsondata">{ "jsondata": "is here" }</script>
```